# xdebug for PHP 5.2 on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: apache, netbeans, 64-bit, debugging, xdebug

Previous posters have linked to http://fusionxlan.com/PHPx64.php to install 64-bit capable versions of xdebug.

I need PHP 5.2 compatibility for Magento, and fusionxlan has disappeared and archive.org doesn't have a copy.

Does anyone have a copy of the fusionxlan download or dll that they can share?

Thanks,
JD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally found a solution to this.  The combination of the recently released (both of them) [Netbeans 6.9](http://netbeans.org/features/php/index.html) and [Xdebug 2.1.0 thread-safe 5.2 VC6 (32-bit)](http://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.2-vc6.dll) works a treat on Windows 7 64-bit.  Oh happy day!

And BTW, the new features in Netbeans 6.9 rock.  Particularly the CSS selector click-thru and auto-complete.